# Fluent NHibernate model first and database first in one project

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to configure fluent nhibernate to create db model based on fluent mapping for some model classes and at the same time have manually (sql) created db tables and a model classes mapped on them in one project?

I am new to nhibernate.

I started to create a model classes and used fluent mapping to created db schema.
Then I wanted to add some logging framework which assumed that db is created manually.

I generated the model classes and mapping classes using NHibernateMappingGenerator.

After I compiled and run my project the logging tables were deleted from the db.

Regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

This code will create the tables for you upon instantiation:

```
public class NHibernateSessionFactory
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                InitializeNHibernateSessionFactory();
            }

            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    private static void InitializeNHibernateSessionFactory()
    {
        _sessionFactory =
            Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard
                .ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL"].ConnectionString))
                .ShowSql())
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<OneOfMyMappedClassesMap>()))
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

The line that is responsible for building your DB based on your mappings is the `ExposeConfiguration` one. The `ShowSql` option will print out all generated SQL code if you use this code in a console application.

Comment: Thanks for replay, I am already using similar code but my problem is slightly different. I have some mappings that are used to create db tables. Then I have some sql code to create other set of tables in the same db, so I run It can create these tables*. Now I need to create a model classes* and model mapping* to be able to use the information stored in tables*. I compile and run my code. The tables* are deleted from db with all information that was already stored. My problem is that I would like somehow to inform NHibernate that tables* are not and cannot be generated from code.

Comment: It the only solution not to generate schema, an to run the sql scripts each time I need to generate the schema again?

Comment: You can do that but you will have to maintain the code manually for every little change you perform to your model which conflicts with the dynamic nature of O/RMs. No matter what workaround you deploy, there will always be a chance that something can go terribly wrong with interacting with your storage. I would suggest you re-examine the reasons why the other tables have to be created manually and if necessary to make some modifications to your model so these changes will be embraced at runtime and all tables will be created from a single ISession/ISessionFactory instance.